# sony vaio SVF153A1YM laptop shuts down after ~30 min

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, shutdown, sony-vaio

I've got a laptop with a Win 10 on it and a a certain point it just started shutting down (in a hard way). I've made following investigation so far:

- tried to run in in BIOS
- removed hard drive
- disconnected the battery
- disconnected WIFI module and USB 3 bus
- replaced RAM with another I have laying around
- checked the cooling paste under the CPU and GPU - all good
- no dust whatsoever
- observed the load and the cpu temp while running win - everything looked good to me

So with the minimal possible setup - bios with most peripherals disconnected it still shuts down.
Have you got any suspicions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a BSOD? Or does it just power down?

Comment: Vaios have a long-standning habit of bad quality capacitators in the power distribution. If they get warm, they can't handle the load and the machine shuts down. Only a replacement mainboard (or a solder job) helps.

Comment: @spikey_richie it's unfortunately a straight power down

Comment: @EugenRieck I will try to find a replacement MB on Ebay although more reasonable would be to replace the caps as the other MB may have similar problems in the future. This is unfortunately beyond my soldering skills (fixing audio cables, guitar amps mods...)